# jQuery append keeps repeating how to just keep one

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple makers on the Map, and I created a custom infoWindow, thus I can manage custom almost everything. I created a var and append to the Div.
but every time on hover, the item add once and keeps repeating.

Here is [**jsfiddle Sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/k5WJK/2/)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        var showcity = '<div class="cities">' + 'This is' + cities[i][0] + '</div>';

        $(".infoWindow").append(showcity).fadeIn(); 

    }
  })(marker, i));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change

```
$(".infoWindow").append(showcity).fadeIn();
```

to

```
$(".infoWindow").html(showcity).fadeIn();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k5WJK/3/)

Comment: You beat me by 7 seconds... grrr

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".infoWindow").append(showcity).fadeIn();
```

should be:

```
$(".infoWindow").html(showcity).fadeIn();
```